BottomSheet with dynamic height and horizontally scrollable ListView
I want to achieve a BottomSheet which adapts in height to its content and contains a short list of horizonal items (max. 20 items).
showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return SafeArea(
                      child: Wrap(
                        children: [
                          ListTile(title: Text('Foo')),
                          ListTile(title: Text('Bar')),
                          Expanded(
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount: 100,
                              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                return Card(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    child: Text("Item $index"),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );

No matter what I try, wrapping in Expanded etc., I always get the error Failed assertion... hasSize.
I would like to achieve a horizontally scrollabe list inside the bottom sheet, like in the picture of the material docs.

You need to wrap your ListView.builder in SizedBox with a height.
Example:
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Wrap(
            children: [
              const ListTile(title: Text('Foo')),
              const ListTile(title: Text('Bar')),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Text("Item $index"),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );


Add your ListView inside SizedBox or Container and give it to specific height, because Expanded takes full height
Try below code:
showModalBottomSheet(
  isScrollControlled: false,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  context: context,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  builder: (context) => Column(
    children: [
      const ListTile(title: Text('Foo')),
      const ListTile(title: Text('Bar')),
      SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Text("Item $index"),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);

Result with SizedBox

Hi Ravindra, can u pls check this...u have given many solutions to my question, pls check this as i needed to learn hive

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79117145/how-to-make-hive-singleton-class-for-saving-datas-like-favourites-cartitem

@IrfanGanatra I have gone your question but Am not aware about Hive. I have try cart application using SqfLite

thanks! So there is no way to wrap the horizontal list with a dynamic height so that the height of the list automatically adapts to the height of it's content?
