How to make hive singleton class for saving datas like favourites cartitem?
I have created a singleton class for saving data to local storage with GetStorage, here I have a bucket named userdata and i want to save favouriteproductids, cartitems and many other list,
With this singleton class its easy to save any kind of data to local storage,
How to do same with Hive?
class MyLocalStorage {

  late final GetStorage _storage;
  static MyLocalStorage? _instance;
  MyLocalStorage._internal();

  factory MyLocalStorage.instance() {
    _instance??=MyLocalStorage._internal();
    return _instance!;
  }

  static Future<void> init(String bucketName) async
  {
    await GetStorage.init(bucketName);
    _instance=MyLocalStorage._internal();
    _instance!._storage=GetStorage(bucketName);
  }


  //save data
  Future<void> saveData<T>(String key,T value) async{
    await _storage.write(key, value);
  }


  T? readData<T>(String key) {
    return _storage.read<T>(key);
  }

  Future<void> removeData(String key) async{
    await _storage.remove(key);
  }

  Future<void> clearAll() async{
    await _storage.erase();
  }

}

uses of this class
void main()async
{
final WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding =
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await GetStorage.init();
  await MyLocalStorage.init('UserData');// bucket name
  
  //saving string list to localstorage
  List<String> favouriteIds=['1','4','5','6'];
  MyLocalStorage.instance().saveData('Favourites', favouriteIds);
  
  
  //saving object list to localstorage
  List<CartModel> cartList=[
    CartModel(productId: '1', title: 'a', qty: 1, amount: 399, imageUrl: ''),
    CartModel(productId: '2', title: 'b', qty: 1, amount: 544, imageUrl: ''),
  ];
  
  MyLocalStorage.instance().saveData('cart', cartList.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList());
  

}


I use a specific id in Isar and just replace the item.
